# Does the compiler/JIT recognize redundant checks?

Tags: java

Lets say we have multiple applications layers, external libraries and the java standard libraries and we are dealing with a string.

At each and every command when you hand in a nullpointer, the application is going to throw an exception. To prevent that, you are supposed to check for a null object and handle it yourself.

Now that means that you check for null, the external libraries check for null and the java standard libraries check for null and potentially some low level c code checks for null.

Isn't that very redundant ? Is this somehow optimized by the compiler and does the branch prediciton normally handle those cases well ?

Comment: The compiler isn't compiling all of those components at the same time...]

Comment: Your code A is checking for null, and then it is using code B which is also checking for null. So where do you want to stop checking for null? If in code B then it could be dangerous because this code could be used in some A1 code which doesn't check for null. So maybe compiler should inform you about skipping that test in your code A. But then what would happen if someone will decide to also skip that test in code B (since it doesn't need to be compiled at the same time as A).

Comment: *"To prevent that, you are supposed to check for a null object and handle it yourself."* Who says? The beauty of exceptions is that they traverse the call hierarchy to get handled at the appropriate level. If you removed all the null checks but handle the NPE at the appropriate level, you don't have redundant checks. If you have an API method that doesn't document that it's okay to pass it a `null`, I would just use what's passed in (without checking it) on the assumption that the code calling the API will either do the check or handle the error. I might also mention it in the JavaDoc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder While the idea may be feasible, it is not entirely true. Imagine several "nested" calls to some libraries. Each offers a public API stating sth. like "If you pass `null`, nothing will happen", and each nesting level will have to ensure this. Regarding the question: It will almost certainly be covered by inlining, but one would have to verify this.

Comment: The Java compiler performs extremely few optimizations. The JIT, on the other hand, will elide null checks that are almost-always non-null.

Comment: @Marco13: I didn't say "If you pass `null`, nothing will happen." I said I'd just use what was passed in, and document what would happen if you passed `null` (e.g., an NPE).

Comment: @chrylis: Indeed. The title just says "compiler," but *which* compiler! :-) The OP probably meant `javac`, but the JIT is where the action is.

Comment: I am interested in the JIT aswell as I was asking about branch prediction aswell. I clarified the title.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My comment referred to *existing* libraries. One library *may* say: "For `null`, nothing will happen" - and therefore, it has to check with `if (string==null) return;`. Otherwise, it may do a call to another library, which also says "For `null`, nothing will happen" - and therefore, it has to check with `if (string==null) return;` *again*. I just wanted to point out that you do not always have full control over the call stack. (In fact: You never have).

Comment: @Marco13: No, of course you only have control over your own code. I read the question as asking about what to do in his/her own code, and was countering the assumption in the question that `null` checks were good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by the comments and the other answers: There are many degrees of freedom and variables involved here. On the highest level, this refers to design principles, aiming at avoiding "meaningful" `null` values, and thus, the explicit `null` checks. (This is difficult sometimes. Some semantically meaningful cases of `null` are built into the standard API). It was also said that redundant `null` checks can not always be avoided, because one never knows from where a method will be called. On lower, technical levels, the distinction between the `javac` compiler and the `JIT` was pointed out. On the lowest level, things like branch prediction may come into play (this has become remarkably famous due to this array processing question...).

---

Referring to the JIT, I was curious about one case that may be particularly interesting for that pattern that you described - namely, whether redundant `null` checks are eliminated during **method inlining**.

I tried to create a simple test for this. But it's harder than expected to create a really *sensible* and *meaningful* test here: My idea was to create a *very* simple version of the chain of method calls that you suggested:

```
public static int processStringA(DummyString string)
{
    if (string == null) return -2;
    return processStringB(string);
}

public static int processStringB(DummyString string)
{
    if (string == null) return -3;
    return processStringC(string);
}

public static int processStringC(DummyString string)
{
    if (string == null) return -4;
    return string.value;
}
```

I spread this over several classes, and added some "dummy instructions" to make it less trivial (but still allow inlining), and ran the following test eventually:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class NestedNullCheckTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            runTest();
        }
    }

    private static void runTest()
    {
        List<DummyString> list = createList();
        int blackHole = 0;
        for (DummyString string : list)
        {
            blackHole += processStringTest(string);
        }
        System.out.println("Result "+blackHole);
    }


    private static int processStringTest(DummyString string)
    {
        if (string == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return NestedNullCheckA.processStringA(string);
    }


    private static List<DummyString> createList()
    {
        List<DummyString> list = new ArrayList<DummyString>();
        Random random = new Random(0);

        for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
        {
            if (random.nextDouble() < 0.1)
            {
                list.add(null);
            }
            else
            {
                list.add(new DummyString(i));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}

class DummyString
{
    int value;
    DummyString(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class NestedNullCheckA
{
    public static int processStringA(DummyString string)
    {
        if (string == null)
        {
            return -2;
        }
        string.value += 1;
        return NestedNullCheckB.processStringB(string);
    }
}


class NestedNullCheckB
{
    public static int processStringB(DummyString string)
    {
        if (string == null)
        {
            return -3;
        }
        string.value -= 2;
        return NestedNullCheckC.processStringC(string);
    }
}


class NestedNullCheckC
{
    public static int processStringC(DummyString string)
    {
        if (string == null)
        {
            return -4;
        }
        string.value *= 2;
        return string.value;
    }
}
```

Running this with

```
java -server -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+PrintAssembly NestedNullCheckTest
```

eventually spilled out the following assembly for the `processStringTest` method:

```
Decoding compiled method 0x00b51488:
Code:
[Entry Point]
[Verified Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} {0x3d90046c} &apos;processStringTest&apos; &apos;(LDummyString;)I&apos; in &apos;NestedNullCheckTest&apos;
  # parm0:    ecx       = &apos;DummyString&apos;
  #           [sp+0x10]  (sp of caller)
  0x00b51580: sub    $0xc,%esp
  0x00b51586: mov    %ebp,0x8(%esp)     ;*synchronization entry
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckTest::processStringTest@-1 (line 30)

  0x00b5158a: test   %ecx,%ecx
  0x00b5158c: je     0x00b515a4         ;*ifnonnull
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckTest::processStringTest@1 (line 30)

  0x00b5158e: mov    0x8(%ecx),%eax
  0x00b51591: shl    %eax
  0x00b51593: add    $0xfffffffe,%eax   ;*imul
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckC::processStringC@13 (line 103)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckB::processStringB@18 (line 90)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckA::processStringA@18 (line 76)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckTest::processStringTest@7 (line 34)

  0x00b51596: mov    %eax,0x8(%ecx)     ;*putfield value
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckC::processStringC@14 (line 103)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckB::processStringB@18 (line 90)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckA::processStringA@18 (line 76)
                                        ; - NestedNullCheckTest::processStringTest@7 (line 34)

  0x00b51599: add    $0x8,%esp
  0x00b5159c: pop    %ebp
  0x00b5159d: test   %eax,0x970000      ;   {poll_return}
  0x00b515a3: ret    
  0x00b515a4: mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  0x00b515a9: jmp    0x00b51599
  0x00b515ab: hlt    
  ...
  0x00b515bf: hlt    
[Exception Handler]
[Stub Code]
  0x00b515c0: jmp    0x00af5e40         ;   {no_reloc}
[Deopt Handler Code]
  0x00b515c5: push   $0xb515c5          ;   {section_word}
  0x00b515ca: jmp    0x00adbfc0         ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00b515cf: hlt
```

Take it with a **huge** grain of salt - one could even consider it as an artifact of an inappropriate test - but at least for this dummy example, one can definitely say:

**Yes, the JIT compiler (sometimes) eliminates redundant checks (for example, during method inlining)**

There is only one `null` check, and one `return` instruction, returning -1, from the topmost method call.

One could now dig through the hoptspot code to find the optimization pass that actually *does* this compaction step, but the general (somewhat broad) answer is that the JIT is remarkably smart in many cases, and *does* eliminate checks that are "obviously" redundant.

Answer (score 4):

> Isn't that very redundant?

Yes it *would be*.  Except that the following is incorrect.

> At each and every command when you hand in a nullpointer, the application is going to throw an exception. *To prevent that, you are supposed to check for a null object and handle it yourself.*

You are not supposed to to do that in Java.  That would be bad practice.

What you are supposed to do is to design your APIs do that there is a clear distinction between semantically meaningful `null` values<sup>1</sup>, and unexpected ones.  For the expected ones, you test.  For the unexpected ones, you (generally speaking) DON'T code your APIs to test for `null`.  Instead you let the JVM detect it and then throw a `NullPointerException`.  (Yes that is correct!)

When an NPE occurs, you get out your debugging tools, and you find and fix the *source* of the `null`.  An NPE is a *symptom* of a bug, not a bug in its own rights.

---

Underneath the covers, there are two ways that a JVM can detect an incorrect use of a `null`:

- It can do an explicit test for the `null` ... which can be optimized locally so that the same null test does not get repeated too much.
- It can attempt the dereference without testing for a `null`.  If the value is indeed a `null`, this leads to segmentation fault hardware exception (assuming that page zero is not mapped) and that can be handled and mapped to a Java exception.

My understanding is (i.e. I've heard) that some JIT compilers choose between the two approaches based on stats gathered during interpretation.

If the JIT compiler emits native code to explicitly test for `null`, then hardware branch prediction should come into play.  The same applies if you code the null tests yourself.  But provided that actual NPEs are rare, the "segfault" approach could well be faster because there is ZERO overhead in the case where the segfault doesn't happen.

The other thing to note is that the JIT compiler will do its best to eliminate any redundant `null` checks that it can detect.  So, for example, if you wrote this:

```
  if (obj != null) {           // explicit null check
      obj.someMethod();        // implicit null check
      obj.someOtherMethod();   // implicit null check
  }
```

the implicit checks would most likely be eliminated.

---

<sup>1 - It is also a good idea to avoid "meaningful" uses for `null` as much as possible.  For example, don't "save space" by using `null` to denote an empty array or collection in an API call.  Require the caller to provide a real empty array or collection ... and you won't have to scatter null checks to deal with the special case.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will not recognize that there were multiple checks for `null` and it is good as it is. Let's suppose you have `method1` and `method2`. `method1` checks whether your `String` is `null` and if not, then calls `method2`. So far, so good.

We can avoid checking for null in `method2`, right? **Wrong**. `method2` might be called from a different place as well, where `null` is not checked. Even if you use only `method1`, a call to `method2` through [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) can occur, which happens long after compilation. The compiler cannot assume that `method2` will never be called outside `method1`.

So, if you and your team have an agreement that `method2` will be called only from `method1`, where the String was checked against `null`, therefore `method2` will not have a null check, then you can assume that it is not null and avoid the check. However, this is micro optimization.